# Higher Resting Heart Rate after WatchOS update on 23-24 Jan 2023

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I have been using Apple Watch SE (1st gen) since September 2022. Recently, I look at my Resting heart rate (RHR), and it shows me that my RHR has been increasing. The spike was on 23-24 Jan 2023, which was the time I updated the WatchOS to the latest version at that time.

The RHR chart in the following days, up until now, seems to be higher than the previous months. I initially thought that my health was getting worse, but when I checked with my friend who used AW SE 2nd gen, he also started to have an increase in RHR on 23-24 Jan, the time he also updated the WatchOS.

Does anyone have the same observation?

Comment: My RHR average over the past year has been 55. There was a period from February - May of 2022 where it was closer to 50 - it dropped and then rose. It certainly could be due to a new algorithm to determine what "resting" means. (I sleep with my watch hence it's so low). I would've installed the watchOS 9 beta in June.

Comment: If the RHR is now stable at the new figure, it is likely an algorithm change in watchOS to determine when you're resting or to trim out erroneous data that might've brought the figure down. If it's still increasing, I would not consider it to be in error - but would then recommend doing other tests (say, comparing walking heart rate) before reaching any conclusions.

Comment: My RHR was about 60-65 before Feb, but then rose to 75 after the update on Jan 2023. Walking heart rate was steady, about 105-120 since Sep.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing any increase on the days you mentioned. I do know that I get far, far better results when I sleep with the watch on. I charge it when getting breakfast routing going and again a short time when I'm reading or such after dinner.

This helps ensure I'm getting a true resting rate and not having it be affected by activities when I get up and don't have the watch on during the quiet times of the day / night for me.

Comment: I always have my watch on, and only charge it when I go to the shower. So far the RHR seems to go down, but it is still higher than what normally recorded before Jan 2023

Comment: I might open a case with Apple support @Minh-LongLuu - sometimes they want some diagnostic data if you are willing to provide them with details. They helped a relative with swim workouts where the new kick detection in the current watchOS was broken for a couple of the initial point releases. You're doing everything else I can think of to get good ratings. No recent tattoo on your arm or change in the melanin content of the skin under the watch or watch band changes?